# Finding data that isn't there

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets say I run a sql query on a user to return contact types.
User A returns three rows:

```
555-1234

555-4321

userA@email.com
```

Now I want to find users who have no phone number but may have an email address. Can anyone give me advice on how I would begin to go about that? If more information is needed please ask.

Edit: Sorry currently on the move. Will post useful data later. For now I can say that there are not strict columns. Eg, Phone1, Phone2, Email.

It's more open, as in the column currently takes a string so it can have a phone number or email. So some users have several entries in the table whereas some may have just one.

I am trying to work out how to find users who have no phone number entries. Hope this makes a little more sense now.

Comment: I don't really understand, you need to find users that have a NULL phone number but have an email ?

Comment: Can you show sample data and expected results?

Comment: Show your tables DDL and the query you use.  Use http://sqlfiddle.com/  (with SqlServer) to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that creates those exact structures online, populate it with testdata and post that.

Comment: Read [why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say,you have tables named **User** and **Contact** and for a user there are multiple contacts in the contact table.

Use the below query to find users who have **no phone number** but may have an email address.

```
SELECT *
FROM User u
 JOIN Contact c ON u.userId = c.userId and c.contactType='Email'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Contact c1 WHERE u.userId = c1.userID and c.contactType='Phone')
```

Comment: Thanks. Reading your answer has totally solved my problem. I was over thinking it by trying to go down some weird route where I was looking for numbers only etc. Didn't occur to me to use the type field. Thanks again.

Comment: Happy to help you.. :)

Comment: @JimmyPop13 i know you got your answer but next time you want to know if a string is a an email or not just search for `@` symbol :D

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean simply "No Phone" because there is no such comparison operator "may have"

Single table:

```
SELECT * FROM Usertable WHERE Phone1 IS NULL AND Phone2 IS NULL
```

User+Contact tables:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Users U
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT * 
          FROM Contacts C 
          WHERE U.UserID = C.UserID AND ContactType = 'Phone'
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

use null check and email column `length` check as you said may email thats why i checked with null or some value

```
select * from users where phone_number is null and (email is null or LEN(trim(email))>0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want users with no phone number:

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (select 1
                  from contact c
                  where u.userId = c.userId and
                        c.contactType = 'Phone'
                 );
```

You don't specify that you actually want the email address (if any), so this should be the most efficient way to get the users.